# Where and when to initialize/create view programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had this question when/where to create and initialize views that are created programatically, so I hope some discussions here will shed more light on this topic for me.

This slide:
[image]

says: *"not to initialize something based on the geometry of the view in viewDidLoad"* and suggests `viewDidAppear`.

Imagine my view controller has view. I want to add 10 dynamic UIButtons to it.
Shall I put the code like below to the **viewDidAppear**?

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    ...
    UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: rect1];
    [self.view addSubview: button1];
    UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: rect2];
    [self.view addSubview: button2];
    ...
}
```

But this creates the buttons each time the view is shown. Is it what we want?
On the other hand if I put the code in `viewDidLoad` slide suggest not to initialize geometry of these views there.

Or shall we **create buttons** in `viewDidLoad` and set their frames in `viewDidAppear`?

What approach do you usually take?

Answer (score 0):

`But this creates the buttons each time the view is shown`. It's true.

So the best thing you can do is to add a boolean (lets name it `isLaunched`). You set it to `FALSE` in the method `-(void)viewDidLoad`

Then add a `if` condition in your `-(void)viewDidAppear` where you perform creation of buttons (or other stuff) and set the boolean to true at the end.

You should have something like that :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //some settings
    isLaunched = FALSE;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(!isLaunched)
    {
        //creating and adding buttons
        isLaunched = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is how I understood  your recommendation I will add also something to it. in the viewDidAppear if `!isLaunched` is true I will **create** and initialize views coordinates. But if `!isLaunched` is false, I may still need to add some setters like setting text of Button if I need to update the title when view reappears. So, basically, if `!isLaunched` is true, I create and initialize the view, but if the condition is false, I can **only** initialize stuff in views, right?

Comment: If you need to do some settings in both case, put your code out of the `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

zbMax (and now Amar) offered good solutions to implement the view creations in `viewDidAppear:` I will provide the rational for doing this (over `viewDidLoad`).

It is pretty simple actually. In `viewDidLoad` none of the views are actually setup yet, so any attempt to set/create frames or bounds will be extremely inconsistent. Struts and springs (or autolayout) will take effect after this method which will create additional changes to your views. `viewDidAppear:` is the correct place to do this because you can now rely on existing views and setting frames.

Comment: It should be noted, however, that `viewDidAppear:` can eventually be called multiple times, so beware of memory leaks, inconsistencies arising out of reallocation or reinitialization of objects, etc.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah, that is why I pointed to one of the other offered solutions for an actual implementation. But thank you for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

Reason for not playing with the geometry in `viewDidLoad` is because view is still in the memory and not on the window. Once the view is put on the window, then you can specify geometry. That happens when `viewDidAppear` is called for your controller.

As recommended, you should do all the initialisation in `viewDidLoad` as this is one time task and need not be repeated. Hold references to the added subviews and give them appropriate frame in `viewDidAppear`.

When you are dealing with custom `UIView` and its subviews, `layoutSubviews` is the method you need to override in the custom view in order to rearrange the geometry of its subviews.

Hope that helps!